# C# chart - difficulty plotting time series with different frequencies

Tags: c#, time-series, mschart

This is my first post on here. I'm attempting to create a 'simple' charting program (windows form based in c#). I say simple because I'm currently only playing around with only 2 series maximum, and a few transformations (percent changes, actual changes, moving averages and moving sums). It will get more complicated than this but having the limited functionality first might help me get a better handle on how all of this works in C#.

I've been searching on and off for a couple of days now but have had no luck so far with my specific situation. I'll try to be as detailed as possible. The user retrieves the time series data from a SQL Server. This part of the program is behaving as expected. I'm creating 2 queries (one for each series) to retrieve the data separately. I do the transformations in the SQL query. Each comes via a SQL adapter which is then placed into a data table. The series may be of different frequencies and the dates may not overlap (i.e. sometimes a stock prices will be daily, and exports will be monthly, or GDP quarterly). The exports number may come in as the first of every month, while stock prices may be missing a value on this date if it was a weekend. I suspect this part is important for my issue.

Nonetheless, I double checked this step and everything works as expected (the values are all coming in correctly at the right dates).

To add those series to a chart, I merge the two data tables like so (I believe this is where my issues are coming from):

```
myTable = myTables1.Copy();
myTables1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { myTables1.Columns["dates"] };

myTables2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { myTables2.Columns["dates"] };

myTable.Merge(myTables2, true);
```

[Datagridview of the Merged data table here looks good to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx6Sz.jpg)

Then I create the chart: I've tried two different methods here. The first is to create each series in a 2 step loop (one for each series) and loop through each row in the table and add an x and y value for each series. I've also tried to set the data source for the chart to be the table, and create 2 series and set the X and Y members as the names of the columns in the table.

Like so:

```
mychart.DataSource = myTable;
```

Then in a loop for each series:

```
mychart.Series.Add(seriesname);
mychart.Series[seriesname].XValueMember = "dates";
mychart.Series[seriesname].YValueMembers = seriesname;
```

Regardless, my second series is always a bit off. Either there are straight lines going across or it misses some values (and by adding a tool tip i can tell that the dates where one series may have a value while the other does not, is where the problems are occurring).

[image]

I'm not looking for help with syntax (just ideas). So my question is: is there a standard or preferred way of getting and plotting series with different frequencies (or which may have different x values)? Alternatively, is there a good source/documentation where i can read up on this? I would add that i have a similar program using visual basic which uses one SQL query regardless of how many series there are. This works in terms of the chart looking as I'd expect it to, but it makes transformations much more complicated given the randomness of the null or empty values in the final table.

Comment: The 'random' line is surely just conecting two disjointed points. Look deeper into your data! _I'll try to be as detailed as possible._ Um, not recommended. Try to be short and concise, so we don't have to read a wall of text. What type are the x-values? Dates or string?? Always try to use numeric or date types, almost never string..!

Comment: I’m confident that they are datetime inputs. I can see this happening if my input is not formatted properly, but it seems to be fine judging from the data table. I’ll explore this avenue and post if i find anything. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I'd like to explore the possibility that i may have disjointed points being connected. I counted the number of points for each series. When i plot two daily series for 2018, i get 239 points. When plot the daily with another monthly series, each series now has 242. The difference is 3 which is exactly how many data points the monthly series had data where the daily one didn't. In other words, the number of points seems to be correct. The issue may be alignment (or the sorting when merging the table), which is what i suspected initially.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything wrong with the data in the datagridview either, which reads from the table. The data is aligned properly and and i can't really think of another way to take a deeper look into the data, as you recommended. How would you go about this?

Comment: I just managed to get it to somewhat display as expected (ish). Since both series had the same number of points, i figured it must be the way empty points are being handled. I added emptypointsstyle (color and border width) and it's plotting all the data accurately. Now i have to deal with the straight lines due to potential empty points at the beginning or end of the x axis. Anyway, i'll look more into how empty points are being treated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: mscharts doesn't work well with strings.  If you are storing your values in the database a strings or NVARCHARs that might be the issue.  I've seen it have the x-axis wrong due to string values.

Comment: Thank you. My x-axis values are all in date format. I suspectnit had something to do with how the chart itself was dealing with empty points. I’m still dealing with what to do about the empy points in the case of transformations. If i do a 3-month percent change for example, the first 2 values are empty, but it shows up as a straight line in the beginning of the chart (because i have the chart plotting the empty points). I may have to programitcally remove these points from the series object in the chart. Still haven’t gotten around to looking into it.